# ffmpeg not capture screenshot on siteground

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, screenshot

I'm using ffmpeg (v5.1) in laravel with PHP 7.4

```
//where to save the image  
$new_file_name = time() . '.jpg';
$image = public_path() . '/uploads/images/' . $new_file_name; //Full path of image
$path = public_path() . '/uploads/' . $path;   //Full path of video
//ffmpeg command to find thumbnail from video
$interval = env('PLAEHOLDER_CAPTURE_TIME', 2);  //time to take screenshot at  
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i $path -ss 00:00:01 -vframes 1 $image 2>&1";
exec($cmd, $output);
var_dump($output); 
exit;
```

It's throwing an error:

> array(32) { [0]=> string(64) "ffmpeg version 5.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers" [1]=> string(25) " built with gcc 12 (GCC)" [2]=> string(128) " configuration: --enable-pic --enable-static --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-doc --disable-avdevice --disable-alsa" [3]=> string(40) " libavutil 57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100" [4]=> string(40) " libavcodec 59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100" [5]=> string(40) " libavformat 59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100" [6]=> string(40) " libavfilter 8. 44.100 / 8. 44.100" [7]=> string(40) " libswscale 6. 7.100 / 6. 7.100" [8]=> string(40) " libswresample 4. 7.100 / 4. 7.100" [9]=> string(130) "Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/customer/www/backend.clavora.com/public_html/public/uploads/videos/1679277906.mp4':" [10]=> string(11) " Metadata:" [11]=> string(26) " major_brand : isom" [12]=> string(25) " minor_version : 512" [13]=> string(39) " compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41" [14]=> string(35) " encoder : Lavf58.45.100" [15]=> string(59) " Duration: 00:00:32.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 515 kb/s" [16]=> string(161) " Stream #0:00x1: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 576x1024 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 380 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)" [17]=> string(13) " Metadata:" [18]=> string(56) " handler_name : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler" [19]=> string(36) " vendor_id : [0][0][0][0]" [20]=> string(104) " Stream #0:10x2: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)" [21]=> string(13) " Metadata:" [22]=> string(60) " handler_name : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler" [23]=> string(36) " vendor_id : [0][0][0][0]" [24]=> string(15) "Stream mapping:" [25]=> string(55) " Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))" [26]=> string(31) "Press [q] to stop, [?] for help" [27]=> string(78) "[auto_scale_0 @ 0x564f48c3b180] Failed to configure output pad on auto_scale_0" [28]=> string(29) "Error reinitializing filters!" [29]=> string(76) "Failed to inject frame into filter network: Resource temporarily unavailable" [30]=> string(55) "Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0" [31]=> string(18) "Conversion failed!" }

Comment: Outputting `$cmd` and running it as the same user works?

Comment: @user3783243
ffmpeg -i /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/clients/EM/clavora/public/uploads/videos/1679647911.mp4 -ss 00:00:01 -vframes 1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/clients/EM/clavora/public/uploads/images/1679647911.jpg 2>&1

Comment: That's half of what I asked. What happens?